# Equation of Peano Curve

Tags: geometry, curves

In 'Space-Filling Curves' by Hans Sagan is presented equation defining the Peano curve.

> Peano, defined a map $f_p$ from $I$ to $Q$ in terms of the operator 
>   $kt_j = 2-t_j(t_j = 0, 1, 2)$ as follows:  $f_p(0_3·t_1t_2t_3t_4...) =
> \begin{bmatrix}0_3·t_1(k^{t_2}t_3)(k^{t_2+t_4}t_5)...\\0_3·(k^{t_1}t_2)(k^{t_1+t_3}t_4)...\end{bmatrix}$,
>   where $k^v$ denotes the $v$th iterate of k.

Where $0_3·...$ denotes a number in base-3. I do not know how to use this formula. Is $k = 2/t_j - 1$ and $k^v$ the $v$th power of $k$? What does it mean that he defined the curve in terms of the operator?

Comment: In my reading, $k$ is a *function* on $\{0,1, 2\}$ which exchanges $0$ and $2$, and $k^t$ means repeated application. Specifically, $k^0=k^2$ doesn't change the digit (is the identity), and $k^1=k$ interchanges digits $0$ and $2$.